# Rendering Large Rectangular Tiled Images with an OpenGL QuadTree

Tags: java, opengl, tree, tile, quadtree

I am currently designing and developing a bespoke imagery viewer for exceptionally large image files (sometimes in the gigapixels). Fortunately these are provided as 256x256 tiles in staged resolution layers, then passed across to OpenGL when required.

The tiles themselves are managed via a QuadTree which seems like a strong solution for "almost power-of-two" images. However given an image with a extremely wide aspect ratio (e.g. 1 gigapixel x 50,000) the model starts to falter with large amounts of null tiles. 
There will only ever be a limited number of tile's on display at a time.

I am using Java 7 with LWJGL to provide an OpenGL Context.
Does a QuadTree solution fit this problem, or are there better alternatives to managing the data?

Edit: Edited the title to make more sense.

Comment: You could add an additional level at the top, splitting up the image into square parts, e.g. 20 image of 50k x 50k, then use quadtrees for the squares.

Comment: How and why do you want to use opengl?

Comment: The current implementation of the system is using Java Graphics2D & JAI to provide the imagery. This is proving to not perform up to scratch. For this reason, it is being changed to an OpenGL approach.
OpenGL is being used for its rendering performance.
I have implemented a more LoD tile based prototype and it seems to be working so far. What would be your thoughts on this @AndreasHaferburg ?
(I understand that a Java system will most likely give less performance then native C++, however Java is a hard-written system requirement.)

Comment: I have developed a renderer similar to what you describe (e.g. Java + OpenGL with a tiling). In my experience using Java is perfectly fine since you do the rendering with OpenGL. You only need a few 100´s of tiles to fill up a screen so the amount of work on the CPU is fairly low. One exception is the decoding of your data which is typically much faster when implemented in c(++). You may also need to be careful with the amount of garbage you produce to ensure smooth FPS.

Using a quad tree has a few advantages:

Answer (score 0):

The quad tree enforces that you split along both coordinate axes. Your problems has a wide aspect so one of the axes will be oversplit.

You have 2 solutions:

- Use BSP. Similar concept but instead of spliting both coordinate ranges you pick one and split that into 2. With this you can split along the large range more often than over the smaller one.
- Use  grid of QuadTrees at the top level. This way you split the space into rough squares so that you make better use of the bits. This was also suggested by @Andreas in the comments.